# Craft CMS site with 5 second server responses?

Tags: craft3

After recent changes on our Craft site and the DB, we are experiencing 5-second server response times. The server checks out and it looks like scripts or the DB itself causing this as a basic HTML test file loads quickly. Not sure how to troubleshoot this, is there an obvious place to look for clues?
any tips are gratefully received!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whoops—using the moderation tools for the first time, and I thought it was going to just take me to an empty comment field, not just post a generic response!

Could you add some details to the question, vis a vis server provider, software, etc? There are _a ton_ of variables that impact performance.

Initially, I'd recommend logging in to the CP and turning on the Debug Toolbar (Front-end or CP) in your user's Preferences pane? This will show you detailed profiling + timing information about the request, and should narrow down the source of the slowness.